# How to prove the function x|x|^2 is infinitely differentiable in Rn space

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

I must show that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$ given by $f(x) = x|x|^2$:

$(i)$ is of class $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$,

$(ii)$ satisfies $f(B(0,1)) \subset B(0,1)$

$(iii)$ and $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at the origin.

for $(i)$, I calculated the limit: $T(x)v = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t} = 2x<x,v>+v<x,x>$

And then, the limit of the rest: $\lim_{v \to 0}\frac{r(v)}{|v|} = \lim_{v \to 0}\frac{f(x+v)-f(x)-T(x)v}{|v|}= 0$

It's differentiable, and $f'(x)$ is continuous, so $f$ is of class $C^1$. My first question is, to prove it is $C^{\infty}$ must I keep doing it? I think it should be similar to $\mathbb{R}$, so it'll end after some steps.

For $(ii)$, as $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous, so it seems ok.

And for the $(iii)$ I'm a bit lost. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are taking an unnecessarily complex approach.

Just think about what ${\lvert x\rvert}^2$ equals to in terms of polynomials, not inner products.

The answer to that question will also help you prove why is $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous at the origin.

Comment: I am not sure Bruno Mazeto reproduced the problem correctly.  Could it have been $x^2 |x|$?

Comment: No. $x$ is an $N$-vector, so $x^2$ is meaningless.

Comment: @MichaelLee I know it's a vector and the quantity that you obtain by taking the inner product with itself DOES have a meaning and can be put in terms of a multidimensional polynomial of its components

Comment: I was replying to @avs, not you. The notation $x^2$ for a vector inner product would be nonstandard.

Comment: @MichaelLee oops, sorry :)

Comment: My bad, misread the problem.:)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm still stuck. I tried to think it as a polynomial, but I got $f(x) = x\sum{x_i^2}$. Where do I go from there?

Comment: @BrunoMazeto compute the Jacobian matrix at $x=0$. Is it invertible? You may want to see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: I think I got the $x|x|^2$ in terms of polynomials and I could calculate the Jacobian at $x=0$. Thank you.